# Dihedral groups textbook example

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Found something in my textbook I don't understand.

When considering Dihedral Groups, the textbook describes properties of dihedral groups:

> Let $r$ be the rotation clockwise about the origin through $\frac{2\pi}{n}$
>   radian.   Let $s$ be the reflection about the line of
>   symmetry through vertex $1$ and the origin.      Then,
>
> 1. $1,r^2,....,r^{n-1}$ are all distinct and $r^n = 1$, so $\mid r \mid = n$
> 2. $\mid s \mid = 2$
> 3. $s ≠ r^i$ for any $i$
> 4. $sr^i ≠ sr^j$, for all $ 0 ≤i, j ≤ n-1$ with $i ≠ j$
> 5. $rs = sr^{-1}$
> 6. $r^is = sr^{-i}$

What I don't understand is the example it provides:

> ...any product of two elements in this form can be reduced to another
>   in the same form using only "relations" $(1),(2), \text{and } (6)$
>   (reducing all exponents mod $n$).
>
> For example, if $n=12$,
>
> $(sr^9)(sr^6) = s(r^9s)r^6 = s(sr^{-9})r^6 = s^2r^{-9+6} = r^{-3} = r^9$

I don't understand where the $s^2$ went, and why $r^{-3} = r^9$ (I suspect this last one is due to $3 \equiv 9 \;(\bmod\; 12)$, but if this is the explanation then I'm also confused why we are using mods on the exponents)

[If needed: I'm reading Dummit/Foote Abstract Algebra 3rd edition]

Comment: Because of 2. we have $s^2=1$, so it goes away.

Comment: You can use modulo $12$ on the exponents because $r^{12}=1$ so changing the exponent by $12$ or a multiple is equivalent to multiplying by $1$.

Comment: For an intuitive explanation of why the power of $r$ is taken mod $n$, recall that $r$ is the rotation of $2\pi/n$ radians. Then $r^n$ means you rotate by that many radians $n$ times, so you rotate $2\pi$ radians, or a full circle, meaning you end up where you started. Hence, $r^n$ does nothing. Similarly, $s$ is a reflection about a line. If you reflect twice consecutively, they cancel each other out and you return to where you started, so $s^2=1$.